# UICollectionViewCompositionLayout with nested groups

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I am trying to build a view that list items and each item has subitems which users can scroll through horizontally (orthogonal scroll).

I know this can be done using a tableview and a horizontal collectionView in each cell, however, I am trying to use the modern UICollectionViewCompositionLayout. Can groups be scrolled through orthogonally or is that only allowed at the section level? Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Could you please share solution for this if you found it.

Comment: I believe i ended up creating a separate collection view for the horizontal scroll